# I'm trying to get a bacic example of AWS transfer manager use working, but their example fails to compile

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to get the basic C++ TransferManager example provided by AWS at:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-sdk-for-c-now-ready-for-production-use/
to build. If fails to compile because it reports that 
Aws::Transfer::TransferManager transferManager(transferConfig);
is an inacessable private function, yet everything I can find on the web uses some variant of this.

The header provides this constructor:

static std::shared_ptr Create(const TransferManagerConfiguration& config);

and even an explicit call to Create() has the same private scope error message.

Can anyone help me with whatever I'm overlooking?

Comment: Perhaps the example is outdated? It's from 2016 - maybe they changed the SDK since then.

Comment: That could well be - if so, I'm hoping someone can point me to one that works